# XMPP file transfer using strophe?

Tags: xmpp

I am using `enyo js` as front end and trying to transfer a file using `xmpp` from my web application. I got a plugin `strophe.si-filetransfer.js`.

For sending message I am using the following:

```
$msg({to   : room,
      type : 'chat'
    }).c('body').t(message);

BoshSession.connection.send(smsg);
```

but I don't know what stanza I want to use for sending the attachment and how?

Answer (score 0):

First add the handler:

```
connection.si_filetransfer.(addhandler);
```

Then the stanza looks something like this (inspect the .js)

```
   connection.si_filetransfer.send(to, sid, filename, size, mime, cb);
```